# How can I see line dylimit() over graph dygraph() in r?

Tags: r

I would like to see the line "Minimo permitido" over the bars in the graph but I dont know how to do it. I wonder if somebody could help with this. I'm using R-Studio 1.2.1335 running in Windows 10.
I'm using dygraph and dylimit for this. You can see my problem in the next images.

**This is what I have:**
[image: This is what I have]

**This is what I would like to have:**
[image: This is what I would like to have]

```r
library(dygraphs)
dygraph((base1,"Titulo del grafico") %>% 
dyAxis("y", label = "Porcentaje de cumplimiento", valueRange = c(0, 110)) %>% 
dyAxis("x", label = "Mes y año", drawGrid = FALSE) %>% 
dySeries(drawPoints = TRUE,label="Resultado", pointShape = "square", color = "lightblue",pointSize=2.5) %>%
dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = ds1.1.1[c(length(ds1.1.1)-12,length(ds1.1.1))]) %>%
dyBarChart() %>% 
dyLimit(95, "Mínimo permitido (95)", strokePattern = "solid", color =     "red")
```

Comment: Maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735999/dylimit-for-limited-time-in-dygraphs

Comment: Created an issue on GitHub as this seems like a useful feature https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/231